# Using variable as text in Google Docs (Using App Script)

Tags: google-apps-script

How do you use a variable in an editAsText line of code? I'm using apps script. Heres my code:

```
function onOpen(e) {
  DocumentApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Check')
      .addItem('Check', 'check')
      .addToUi();
}
```

```
 function check() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  var result = ui.prompt("Enter change text");
  Logger.log(result.getResponseText());
  Logger.getLog
  var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
  body.editAsText(' '+ result);

  
  }
```

As you can see in the code, I tried adding the variable 'result' with an editAsText line, but that just gave me the error

`Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for DocumentApp.Body.editAsText.`

`check`

`@ Check.gs:7`

Comment: getLog should be getLog()